# Can I split this string to obtain the info I require?

Tags: php, regex, database, string, split

I've been given this project where the user can fill forms to solve job-related problems and I was asked to obtain the info filled from each person so they can see all the forms they've sent, but it is all stored in one database column and I'm not sure if i'll be able to split this long string.

First, this is the string that gets saved into the db:

```
a:20:{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:9:"-name";s:0:"Alvaro";s:13:"-lastname";s:0:"Alvaro";s:10:"-email";s:19:"mail@mail.es";s:15:"-tipoconsul";s:10:"Vacaciones";s:13:"-fecharec";s:10:"2018-08-09";s:14:"-fechaalta";s:10:"2017-11-01";s:18:"-CategoriaProf";s:19:"Tecnico electronico";s:18:"-NombreEmpresa";s:30:"Inversiones Tecnicas G&F S.L. ";s:21:"-ActividadEmpresa";s:29:"venta de equipos electronicos";s:18:"-DireccEmpresa";s:15:"calle falsa 123";s:15:"-telEmpresa";s:9:"555555555";s:20:"-ContactoEmpresa";s:6:"Alvaro";s:16:"-Comentarios";s:8:"Probando";s:18:"-comunicacion1";s:0:"";s:18:"-comunicacion2";s:0:"";s:9:"-nom1";s:0:"";s:9:"-nom2";s:0:"";s:13:"-contrat1";s:0:"";s:13:"-contrat2";s:0:"";}
```

In this example I would need to get the following info to display:

- "Alvaro"
- "Alvaro"
- "mail@mail.es"
- "Vacaciones"
- "2018-08-09"
- "2017-11-01"
- "Tecnico electronico"
- "Inversiones Tecnicas G&F S.L."
- "venta de equipos electronicos"
- "calle falsa 123"
- "555555555"
- "Alvaro"
- "Probando"
- Both comunicacion1 and comunicacion2 (which are empty in this case)
- All of the following nom and contrat fields

I have tried exploding the string many times, but there is no good separator for doing so and at this point I think I've tried every possible combination of :  ;  _  " "

```php
<?php 
    $info = explode(" ", $resultado->form_value); 
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    while ($i < count($info)) {
        // echo $info[$i];
        $info2 = explode("_", $info[$i]);
        while ($j < count($info2)) {
            echo $info2[$j];
        $j++;
    }
    $i++;
    }
?>
```

This one is the closest I've been, but as you can see there is still a lot of info left that does not appear in the final string

I don't know thath much about regular expressions, I've tried creating one but I don't quite understand the syntaxis, nor I really know if this string is splitable with all the punctuation signs that it has.
Once again thank you for your time and patience, all the help I can get is really appreciated!

Comment: Try using `unserialize()` and you will get an array

Comment: Except somehow the serialised data appears to have been corrupted. Did you do anything to it before posting it

Comment: If you can't get `unserialize` to work because the serialized array is corrupt, you could split on double quote and then iterate through your array only taking every other item (<array index>%2=0).

Comment: Was this originally in a multi byte charater set like UTF-8? And somehow its got converted to simple ascii somewhere in the fiddle process?

Comment: Thank you all guys! As you said I only had to use unserialize() method, which I dind't knew until now. It worked fine for me, so I may have made a mistake copying it.
Thank you again for the quick answer @RiggsFolly and JNevill!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was suggested, the solution was to apply unserialize() method to the string, effectively converting it into an array.